# Scope of "this" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript class that looks like this:

```
function SomeFunction()
{
    this.doSomething(function()
    {
        this.doSomethingElse();
    });

    this.doSomethingElse = function()
    {

    }
}
```

This code throws an error because the scope of "this" inside the function that is passed into doSomething() is different that than the scope of "this" outside of that function.

I understand why this is, but what's the best way to deal with this?  This is what I end up doing:

```
function SomeFunction()
{
    var thisObject = this;

    this.doSomething(function()
    {
        thisObject.doSomethingElse();
    });

    this.doSomethingElse = function()
    {

    }
}
```

That works fine, but it just feels like a hack.  Just wondering if someone has a better way.

Comment: @Jon Kruger That's what I do, too.  I think that's pretty normal.  You can change `this` with `call` and `apply`, but that doesn't always fit what you're doing well.  Another option is passing `this` as a parameter, but that feels like even more of a hack.

Comment: @Jonathon What do you mean by "You can change this with call and apply"?

Comment: @Jon Kruger See this, check out their article for `call`, too: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/Apply

Comment: JavaScript: The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford is a good reference that goes over this very question.

Comment: @Jonathon Yes!!!!!  "call" is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: also remember that if you call SomeFunction without the new operator (eg. SomeFunction(); ) this refers to window.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This commenter had what I was looking for (although the other answers are good too):

@Jon Kruger See this, check out their article for call, too: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/Apply– Jonathon 44 mins ago

Answer (score 11):

That is the correct and commonly-accepted workaround. It's sort of kludgy but it's what everybody does. Typically this extra variable is named `self`, as in:

```
function SomeFunction()
{
    var self = this;

    this.doSomething(function()
    {
        self.doSomethingElse();
    });

    this.doSomethingElse = function()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that `self` is a property of the window object in browsers that points at itself, though this is unlikely to cause any problems.

Comment: Other names i've seen used quite a bit are `that` and `me`, depending on context.

Answer (score 3):

`this` has dynamic "scope". That means that it is set up by whatever binds it, and `this` is bound by a "method call". That is, *any* time in your program you see this: `w.f()` then while `f` is executed, `this` is dynamically bound to `f`, *even* if `f` had `this` in its lexical scope.

Most JavaScript frameworks provide some facilities for dealing with this exact problem. With [Prototype.js](http://www.prototypejs.org/) (for example) you can do this:

```
this.doSomething(function() { this.doSomethingElse(); }.bind(this));
```

Your "hack" however is fine. I usually do a `(function (self) { ... })(this)` around any  functions that I need a lexically-scoped `this`-like variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth mentioning that the next version of ECMAScript (the language spec for JavaScript) is going to introduce `Function.bind()`, which will let you specify a permanent context for a function.