# why can't I access this.property in my object literal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just been restructuring my code into objects and using the this keyword, I've got this problem whereby, setting the prop works, but then when the second method fires, `myProp` is undefined. I've noticed if I use `myObj` to set and get rather than this it works fine. What's the difference here? What am I doing wrong? I though this was referring to the instance of which there is only one which was automatically instantiated by the object literal.

```
var myObj = {
    SetProp: function (id) {
        this.myProp = "abc";
        Ajax.GetJSONAfterStandardLogic(Utility.PrefixURL("/ajax/mymethod"), this.SetPropSuccess);
    },
    SetPropSuccess: function (response) {
        console.log("test " + this.myProp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `this` refers to the function `SetPropSuccess` in that context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scope of "this" in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253955/scope-of-this-in-javascript) <-- there are many, but this is the first one I came across with a well stated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely because when you call those functions, `this` is not the object. `this` is the binding with which the function was called.

A bit more code to demonstrate how you're calling the function would be useful, but you can make it work by using:

```
myObj.SetProp.call(myObj, id)
```

This binds myObj as `this`, for the SetProp function call.

If you put `console.log(this)` in either of those functions, you'll probably find that `this` is not what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

When your callback function is executed, it's in a different scope.  As such "this" references that scope and your "myProp" is not defined.  That's why using myObj.myProp works - the scope remains valid.

Cheers

Comment: `this` isn't set by scope, it's set by how a function is called.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` variable is set according to how a function is called. When you use `objectReference.method()` "dot" syntax `this` will automatically be set to the object. You can also call a function and explicitly set `this` to some other object by using `.call()` or `.apply()`.

In your case, when you pass `this.SetPropSuccess` as a callback function you are passing a reference to the function and when it is then called by `GetJSONAfterStandardLogic()` it is not called in a way that sets `this` to your object (most likely it will be equal to `window`). You can work around the problem by saving a reference to the object in a local variable of `SetProp()`:

```
var myObj = {
    SetProp: function (id) {
        var self = this;
        this.myProp = "abc";
        Ajax.GetJSONAfterStandardLogic(Utility.PrefixURL("/ajax/mymethod"),
                                       function() { self.SetPropSuccess(); });
    },
    SetPropSuccess: function (response) {
        console.log("test " + this.myProp);
    }
}
```

Through the magic of closures, the anonymous function that I've added as a callback to pass to `GetJSONAfterStandardLogic()` has access to the variables in its containing scope `SetProp()` *even after* `SetProp()` *has finished executing*.

Bottom line is that you have to get used to `this` in JavaScript working very differently to the way it works in class-based OO languages like Java and C#. JavaScript is still OO, but these differences usually trip up people coming to the language from Java or C#.

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this