# Javascript callbacks losing 'this'

Tags: javascript, object, callback, this, scope

I have an issuer where I lose the `this` inside this object. The output of the following piece of JavaScript gives me `"some-id"` and then `undefined`. When I use `this` inside a callback function, the scope goes out of the object and it cannot use `this` any more. How can I get the callback to use 'this' or at least have access to the object?

Since I will make multiple objects, I won't be able to create a 'static' like storage.

Here is my test code that you can use to reproduce my problem. What I would like to have is `CheckBox.doSomething()` to return the value of `this.id` which should match `some-id` for this test case.

```
function CheckBox(input_id) {
    this.id = input_id;
    this.doSomething();
    $('#some-element').click(this.doSomething);
}

Checkbox.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    alert(this.input_id);
}

var some_box = new CheckBox('some-id');
some_box.doSomething();
$('#some-element').click();
```

I can't even get this to work as I want it to:

```
function CheckBox2(input_id) {
    this.id = input_id;
    alert(this.id);
}

CheckBox2.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    alert(this.input_id);
}
var some_box = new CheckBox2('some-id');
some_box.doSomething();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [scope-of-this-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253955/scope-of-this-in-javascript)

Comment: @Lucero that technique is only available for dynamically created functions, not those in prototype.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/javascript events - prototype event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018564/jquery-javascript-events-prototype-event-handler)

Comment: Related: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484) and [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
function CheckBox(input_id) {
    this.id = input_id;
    this.doSomething = $.proxy( this.doSomething, this );
    $('#some-element').click(this.doSomething);
}
```

The "javascript equivalent" of this is `Function#bind` but that is not available in every browser and since it seems you are using jQuery I am using the jQuery equivalent `$.proxy`

Comment: yes I can see that.. Too much javascript for 1 day :3 Thanks a lot!! Now I understand why I had so many issues with undefined variables earlier with different methods of creating objects. Thanks for the clear examples

Answer (score 21):

Your problem is with this line: `$('#some-element').click(this.doSomething);`

#### Why this is a problem

JavaScript methods don't know anything about the object that should be assigned to `this`, it's set when the method is called either explicitly (with `myFunction.call(obj)`) or implicitly (when called using `obj.myFunction()`).

For example:

```
var x = {
    logThis: function () {
        console.log(this);
    }
};

x.logThis(); // logs x
x.logThis.call(y); // logs y

var func = x.logThis;
func(); // logs window: the fallback for when no value is given for `this`
```

In your case, you're passing `this.doSomething` to jQuery, which is then explicitly calling it with the element that was clicked as the value of `this`. What's happening is (a slightly more complex version of) this:

```
var callback = this.doSomething;
callback.call(anElement, anEvent);
```

#### The solution

You need to make sure that `doSomething` is called with the right value of `this`. You can do that by wrapping it in another function:

```
var cb = this;
$('#some-element').click(function() {
    return cb.doSomething();
});
```

jQuery provides a [`proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function lets you do this more simply:

```
$('#some-element').click(jQuery.proxy(this.doSomething, this));
```

Comment: In this case `some_box.doSomething();` is already giving me 'undefined' when I call it.. How is that possible? I'm not using any callbacks there

Comment: There's a typo in your code: In the constructor function you're setting `this.id` but in the `doSomething` function you're referencing `this.input_id`

Comment: I'd put more emphasis on using $.proxy, it allows your class to be extendable and keep all functions neatly in prototype

Comment: @Esailija: I think it's more beneficial to understand why the code doesn't work, rather than just knowing a specific way of solving the problem. If you're going to do tricks like `this.func = $.proxy(this.func, this)` then you should really understand how and why it works, which I'm sure you do, but others reading your answer might not.

Comment: @georgebrock I didn't mean to compare to my answer, just wanted to point out that saying function binding is merely a simpler way is an understatement because it has a lot of other benefits as well. Regardless, yours is obviously a better answer.

Answer (score 4):

Others have already explained the causes of the problem and how to fix it with jQuery. What's left is how you fix it with standard JavaScript. Instead of ...

```
$('#some-element').click(this.doSomething);
```

... you write:

```
document.getElementById('some-element').addEventListener('click', this.doSomething.bind(this));
```

This changes the context of `this` inside `doSomething`. You can also do that with anonymous functions - instead of ...

```
$('#some-element').click(function(event) {
    console.log(this);
});
```

... you write:

```
document.getElementById('#some-element').addEventListener('click', (function(event) {
    console.log(this);
}).bind(this));
```

That has been very useful to me in projects with lots of callbacks, e.g. in Node.js (where you don't have to care about outdated browsers).

Edit: `getElementById()` and `addEventListener()` instead of `$(...).click(...)`.