# Best way to send "this" object to callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Lately a lot of my code has been looking like this...

```
function MyObjectClass (selector) {
    this.color  = "red";
    this.$elt   = $(selector);
    // ... any other object vars here ...

    // Example method for the object
    this.showThenUpdateColor = function () { 
        // Keep a copy of "this" to use for callbacks
        var o = this;
        // Example of jQuery function that accepts a callback           
        o.$elt.fadeIn(function(){ 
            // Inside of this callback function we need to access the main object
            o.$elt.css({
                "background-color" : o.color // This is where we need the "o"
            });
        });
    }
}
var myObject = new MyObjectClass('#myObject');
myObject.showThenUpdateColor();
```

...where I have a callback inside of an object method. Typically I assign the object itself ("this") to a local variable (usually "o" because it's short and easy) which can be used in the callback.

Is this an **optimal use of memory**? Is there any danger of memory leaks? Is there a better way?

Comment: I just add this link[1] to the discussion, it's interesting. The answers (not only the accepted one) give a good explanation of how to handle "this". Anyway your question is different: "Is this an optimal use of memory?". This is why I'm providing this in a comment, and I will follow the discussion.

[1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766407/javascript-callbacks-losing-this

Comment: Yes, no, and no - there are only *other* ways. See [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Thanks Bergi, that's the basic answer I was looking for. Although the ideal answer would include some explanation of how we know it is the optimal use of memory. When I set `var o = this;` that just creates a reference to the object which i assume is very small in memory? Also not sure if the closure has some memory implications?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend having a look at [jQuery.proxy()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/). It lets you create a function that, when executed, executes another function in the scope you specify. You could then write:

```
this.showThenUpdateColor = function () { 
    // Example of jQuery function that accepts a callback           
    this.$elt.fadeIn($.proxy(this._onFadeInComplete, this));
}

function _onFadeInComplete() {
    this.$elt.css({
        "background-color" : this.color
    });
}
```

Comment: The nice thing about using `function _onFadeInComplete` instead of `this._onFadeInComplete = function()...` is that it's private to `MyObjectClass`, i.e. nothing can call it from outside of the class.