# Cannot target div using 'this' inside a function inside 'each' function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, this

So I just want these mice to come back up after a random time when you click them. I am trying to use the each function to target each .mouse div, which works fine, however if I put 'this' again in the settimeout function they don't come back. If I target 1 specific mouse like the below example that 1 comes back as expected. Its clearly not taking the 'this' of the each function through into the next function.

The code below had '.mouse-1' but this is where I would like 'this'

http://thetally.efinancialnews.com/tallyassets/wackamouse/index.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="mice">
    <div class="mouse mouse-1"></div>
    <div class="mouse mouse-2"></div>
    <div class="mouse mouse-3"></div>
    <div class="mouse mouse-4"></div>
    <div class="mouse mouse-5"></div>
    <div class="mouse mouse-6"></div>
    <div class="mouse mouse-7"></div>
    <div class="mouse mouse-8"></div>
    <div class="mouse mouse-9"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

^ The html is very simple. Absolutely positioned mice on an image. They just need to duck down then come back after a random amount of time

```
$('.mouse').each(function() {

$(this).click(function() {

$(this).animate({
'background-position-x': '0',
'background-position-y': '40px'
}, 300, function() {

var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (7000 - 2000)) + 500; //between 7secs and 2.5 secs
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.mouse-1').animate({
 'background-position-x': '0',
 'background-position-y': '0'});
            },  rand);

    });

});

});
```

Also, on a side note, I'd like the mouse divs to be unclickable when they go down

Thanks alot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript callbacks losing 'this'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766407/javascript-callbacks-losing-this)

Comment: 1. Including a fiddle or something would help --  at the very least the HTML.

2. Im not sure for certain whether this would work or not, but try:


$('.mouse').each(function() {

var that = this;

...


Then using `that` to reference each mouse in the $setTimeout function?

Comment: You can use `var ref = this;` then use ref instead of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind this so you can have it in the scope of the setTimeout:

```
 $('.mouse').each(function () {

    $(this).click(function () {

        $(this).animate({
            'background-position-x': '0',
                'background-position-y': '40px'
        }, 300, function () {

            var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (7000 - 2000)) + 500;
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(this).animate({
                    'background-position-x': '0',
                        'background-position-y': '0'
                });
            }.bind(this), rand);

        }.bind(this));

    });

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q5tdhyo4/)

Comment: @bboybeatle sec adapted it to your code check the edit for the demo

Comment: Simply needs to be adapted to take in your rand function for the time, other than that should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, somehow it works without the extra bind. Any idea how i'd make them non-clickable as well when they've animated until they come back?

Comment: Add a class once clicked, and check if they have the class in the click  handler :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.mouse').each(function() {

$(this).click(function() {
var $mouse = $(this); 
$(this).animate({
'background-position-x': '0',
'background-position-y': '40px'
}, 300, function() {

var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (7000 - 2000)) + 500; //between 7secs and 2.5 secs
setTimeout(function(){
    $mouse.animate({
 'background-position-x': '0',
 'background-position-y': '0'});
            },  rand);

    });

});

});
```

Comment: This also worked. Thanks. I might use this as I understand the concept more than binding

Comment: Binding simply passes the context to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```

```
$('.myMouse').each(function() {

$(this).click(function() {
var that = this;

$(this).animate({
'background-position-x': '0',
'background-position-y': '40px'
}, 300, function() {

var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (7000 - 2000)) + 500; //between 7secs and 2.5 secs
setTimeout(function(){
    $(that).animate({
 'background-position-x': '0',
 'background-position-y': '0'});
            },  rand);

    });

});

});
```